# Units on the electrostatic force equation

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, units, coulombs-law

So here we have the electrostatic equation:

Fe = Ke * q1 * q2 / r^2

The units of the constant Ke are N*m^2/C^2

And this is because we want it to cancel out with the product of q1 and q2 which unit is C^2 and the r^2 which unit is m^2; and leave us with the F units for force.

My question is:

Why are we giving these units to the product of q1 and q2 and r^2?
Why aren't the units still just Coulombs and Metres without the square.

I see the point of having the unit of an area having a square so like m^2 because it indicates it is an area that we are talking about; but in this case we square the distance not to find out an area but we just need it to work out the equation; same with the the two charges what are we trying to indicate with C squared (C^2)?

If we instead just used the units m and C with no squares the unit of the constant could simply be:

N*m/C, right?

But that's not important; I would be grateful if someone could explain to me why we use these units for the product of the two charges and the distance squared. Because I assume we aren't talking about area so it's kind of misleading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you have to observables $A$ and $B$ with units $[A]$ and $[B]$ then the units of the product $AB$ is $[AB] = [A] \, [B]$. This is the reason why we measure areas with $\mathrm m^2$ and not the other way around.

If you get really into Electrodynamics you will however understand that the dependency $1/r^2$ has something to do with an area. In particular let's write the Coloumb-Force law in SI units:

$$F = \frac 1{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q^2}{r^2} = \frac 1{\epsilon_0} \frac{q^2}{4 \pi r^2} = \frac 1 {\epsilon_0} \frac{q^2}{\mathcal A}$$

where $\mathcal A = 4\pi r^2$ is the area of the sphere with radius $r$.

If you are familiar with Maxwell's equations you can show that this is by no means a coincidence. If we have a point particle with charge $Q$ then from Gauss' law we have:

$$\int_{\mathbb S^2_r} \vec E \cdot \mathrm d\vec{A} = Q/\epsilon_0$$

where $\mathbb S^2_r$ is the sphere with radius $r$. From the symmetry of the problem, we know that the electric field must have spherical symmetry hence:

$$E \,\int_{\mathbb S^2_r} \mathrm d A = E \, \mathcal A= Q/\epsilon_0 \implies E = \frac 1{\epsilon_0}\frac{Q}{\mathcal A} $$

since the area integral just gives the area of the sphere $\mathcal A$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Okay, yeah I did think that it might actually have something to do with an area that's good to know. And I sure will get more into electrodynamics. I just started reading this field and wanted to get the questions I had out the way as soon as possible. Anyway the rest of your answer other than the first paragraph is way beyond my understanding, at least at this point haha. Thank you so much for your answer though! Or... reading it over again, it is starting to make some more sense. :D

Comment: I am glad that it helped. After you have learned more about it you can always come back and read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

But by your logic, shouldn't we just say that the area of an object should just be metres? Then what would distinguish that from units of length? There would also be no way to distinguish (from your units) the difference between the electric force, electric field, electric potential energy or electric potential! This would get very confusing.

Units are simply a function of dimensional analysis in a given equation. To define it differently for the electric force or any equation for that matter would make no sense.

However, you could adjust the physical constant to be 1 itself, thus having no need for the constant in the first place.
See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! (can't press enter for some reason) I see the point in using these units now I suppose, can't say I fully understand it yet but I see it. Maybe once I read deeper into this field it'll make more sense to me. Thanks again!